# Firebase Storage image download extremely slow

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing an IOS app in which I have posts that get fetched from the firestore database. Each post contains references to the firebase storage, where the corresponding images are stored. When I want to download the images, it takes ages for them to be downloaded, around 10-15 seconds. I load them asynchronous. I tried downloading them via

- the firebase SDK getData() method
- downloading the url and then downloading the content behind the URL
- downloading them via passing the url into an asyncImageView

However, none of these methods achieve any good results that could be used for a decent UX. How can I make this faster?

Previous answers suggested making the storage public... Isn't displaying them via the URL a public method?

If it is not and I have to make it public, how can I prevent that everybody can see every image, whether it is a user of the app or not. Is it possible to have a "public" storage but still not making it accessible for everyone?

Should I change to a different provider?

Code:

```
func orderedImageDownload3(imageRefs: [String], doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot){
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var images = [UIImage]()
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    for ref in imageRefs {
        let fileRef = storageRef.child(ref)
        group.enter()
        fileRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle any errors
                print(error)
            } else {
                //Do the download
                if let url = url {
                    self.getImage(from: url) {data, response, error in
                        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
                        print("Download Finished")
                        // always update the UI from the main thread
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data){
                            images.append(image)
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        //put images into observable object
    }
    }
    
    
func getImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check you connectivity and internet speed? How big are the pictures? Maybe you need to ore process them and decrease their size

Comment: Yes, internet speed is sufficient, other apps/websites work perfect. Average image size around 2.5 MB

Comment: 2.5mb is a lot. Try reducing the size. For mobile devices usually (depends on your goal) a few hundreds kb size images should still look good. The fact that you are downloading several images at once might slow down the process as well.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will try to compress them further! However, if I download from the given url with my browser for example, the download happens immediately. This is not possible via the three methods above?

Comment: Do you download several pictures in parallel from your device? Or only one? Or one by one?

Comment: I included one option of the code above, does not matter which of the three options I use, always way to long.

Comment: @sgg1999 - it seems unlikely you would be displaying more than one 2.5mb image at a time... so, as a general rule, the approach is to have "thumbnail" images for multi-image display, and only download the *big* image when needed. Or, if you think you're definitely going to need them, download the thumbnails and then immediately start background-downloading of the large images.

Comment: You are also adding additional overhead with the async call to get the image URL. This can be avoid by making them public

Comment: @DonMag I download 5 images per post. They are displayed in a TabView, it will look like instagram, so for each post you can horizontally scroll through the five images. The posts get scrolled vertically. I always display them in the same format, meaning I don't tab on the images to open them but just scroll horizontally through them.

Comment: @CloudBalancing what exactly means making them public? And what if I only want certain users to be able to display them?

Comment: @sgg1999 - if you're trying to populate multiple posts (rows) each having **5 x 2.5mb** files, that's a ***lot*** of data to transfer. If you are not allowing zooming of individual images, you almost certainly want to make them smaller. You could also create highly compressed / lower resolution (so, small file size) images that get downloaded and displayed first, and then replace them with the less compressed / higher resolution images as they arrive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would have never thought it but it works much better! I download the highly compressed images via URL into an async image, what is the best practice for instagram like apps, downloading yourself and displaying it in an image view or putting it into an async image?

Comment: Since you're pulling the data into your code, is there any specific reason why you're not using the `getData` API that is shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_in_memory)? Using that API allows you to skip the additional call to get the download URL, which should speed things up a bit (although it won't make any difference for the data transfer speed).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I ended up using my implementation for AsyncImage, so I just pull the url into an AsyncImageView. I did implement it like I did in the code just to try different variants.